# Elasticsearch SIEM is not working, but EQL query is ok

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I got some problems with my ELK running on docker.
I made ssl on tls and http and tryied to make simple EQL-query:

```
sequence by winlog.computer_name 
[iam where event.code == "4720"] 
[iam where event.code == "4726"]
```

When i click on show results i see hits [preview of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tUxP.png)

but when i'm trying to reproduce alert it's zero hits in index

> .siem-signals-default-*

I got some warns from my elasticsearch-container:

> {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-25T12:37:33,433Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport", "cluster.name": "elastdocker-cluster", "node.name": "elastdocker-node-0", "message": "received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.20.0.5:9200, remoteAddress=/172.20.0.2:43450}", "cluster.uuid": "oZsivcyzROWSooXVIPzbKQ", "node.id": "KIjWJ0OjSW-lYt51cO8ViQ"  }

Where is the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This helps:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "xpack" : {
      "monitoring" : {
        "migration" : {
          "decommission_alerts" : "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transient" : { }
}
```